# Select data within today

Tags: sqlite

I want to have query fetch all record falls with in today,

```
SELECT * from table where createddate >=  select date(‘now’) and createddate <=select date(‘now’)
```

This query not working.

Below query working

```
SELECT * from table where createddate >= '2017-11-17 00:00:00' and createddate <= '2017-11-17 23:59:59'
```

but I want to construct query like

```
SELECT * from table where createddate >=  select date(‘now 00:00:00’) and createddate <=select date(‘now 23:59:59’)
```

Comment: What is the exact format of the values in the table?

Comment: created date is datetime format

Comment: There are many possible formats.

Comment: YYYY-mm-dd hh:MM:ss

Answer (score 0):

The `date()` function returns the date as a string in `YYYY-mm-dd` format. To add the time, simply concatenate the desired time values:

```
WHERE createddate BETWEEN date('now') || ' 00:00:00'
                      AND date('now') || ' 23:59:59'
```

If you do not have an index on this column, or if speed does not matter, you can simply strip the time from the column value first:

```
WHERE date(createddate) = date('now')
```